# Created a zpool without dataset

Tags: zfs

I have a long existing zpool constisting of 2 disks.
Now i think i originally did not explicitly created a filesystem in the pool like: pool/myfilesystem.
So my data resides in the root of the pool (i guess the pool itself is also a filesystem)

> ```
> zpool status
>   pool: zfs-samba
>  state: ONLINE
>     NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
>     zfs-samba   ONLINE       0     0     0
>       mirror-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
>         sdb     ONLINE       0     0     0
>         sdc     ONLINE       0     0     0
> ```

```
zfs list
NAME                    USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
zfs-samba               427G   472G   190G  /zfs-samba
zfs-samba@20180305     2,24G      -   129G  -
zfs-samba@20180324     2,71G      -   130G  -
a lot of snapshots...
```

The zfs list command shows the pool name:zfs-samba with **no** embedded filesystem.

Can i correct this and 'move' all the data including snapshots to
a filesystem like: zfs-samba/myfilesystem ?
If this is not possible, how should i copy all data + snapshots to a
newly create filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

This is the root dataset, so, you can't rename nor delete it. The root dataset is created along pool creation.

However, you can create a snapshot of the root dataset along with a snapshot of the child datasets, then, clone them by running `zfs clone tank@snapshot tank/target`.

If you need to include all the snapshots, you need to use `zfs send-recv`. This has been answered at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/440632/zfs-rename-move-root-filesystem-into-child).

Answer (score 1):

So I think the best way to correct this:

- Break the mirror
- Delete the pool in dsk1, recreate pool + filesystem inside root filesystem
- Zfs send-recvfrom dsk2 to dsk1
- Delete pool in dsk2, add dsk2 to mirror with dsk1

Is this a safe way?